# Snowflake a working procedure is not being successfully executed when calling it within a scheduled task

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a fully running procedure on snowflake with no errors at all when calling it:

```
call ADD_MONTHLY_OBSERVATION_VALUES('@test_azure_blob_stg/Monthly_Report.csv', 'GENERIC_CSV_FORMAT');
```

I wanted to wrap this command into a task and schedule it to a specific time like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK ADD_MONTHLY_OBSERVATION_VALUES_TASK
    WAREHOUSE = 'DEV_WH'
    TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
    //SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 6-7 * * SUN,MON,TUE,WED,THU Asia/Dacca'
    //Schedule for each minute
    SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON * * * * * UTC'
AS
    call ADD_MONTHLY_OBSERVATION_VALUES('@test_azure_blob_stg/Monthly_Report.csv', 'GENERIC_CSV_FORMAT');
```

And then I resumed the task to work:

```
ALTER TASK ADD_MONTHLY_OBSERVATION_VALUES_TASK RESUME;
```

When I checked the history of the task:

> STATE: SUCCEEDED
>
> ERROR_CODE: NULL
>
> ERROR_MESSAGE: NULL
>
> QUERY_START_TIME: 2021-01-27 16:00:06.198 -0800
>
> COMPLETED_TIME: 2021-01-27 16:00:24.902 -0800
>
> RETURN_VALUE: NULL

Actually the procedure will return a string `DONE` when everything have been successfully added/updated.

When running:

```
show tasks;
```

The procedure's state is `started`.

Why the procedure is not being executed when called using a task?

There was new data uploaded to the staged file from Azure, so the procedure should detect the new submissions and start the insert process.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the procedure outside the task, you have to use the task owner role to ensure correct testing. If your procedure works outside the task with task owner privileges, it should also work within the task.

So... I assume there is a problem with your access/rights management. SQL statements executed by the task can only operate on Snowflake objects on which the role has the required privileges. --> You have to grant more privileges on the objects within your procedure to your task owner role.

See more here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html

Comment: but I am able to resume the task which I was already granted an access to do so.

Comment: Sure, but: It looks like your procedure references some objects or does some operations, the task owner role has not privileges to. That's what I mean.

Comment: I just noticed that I am using the same role to run both procedures and tasks. Anyway, i will let the admin account run the tasks and we will see then.

Comment: Okay, this is a good hint and I'll think about other reasons. Please let me know what your test shows up.

Comment: Thanks. Sure I will.

Comment: how to grant ownership of a task to my account as well?